# Add new column in sql table

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert new column in existing table with 2nd position.

Now i have columns order like

```
Emp_id, Emp_Name, Address, phoneNo.
```

I want to add "Gender" in near Emp_Name.

```
Emp_id, Emp_Name, Gender, Address, phoneNo).
```

I can't delete this table and create new table.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/08/sql-server-change-order-of-column-in-database-tables/

Comment: Why do you want to add it to that specific position?

Comment: just i gave example. I want to implement in another table.we need to follow uniform for all tables.

Comment: @user2354274 Order of a column in a table is not very relevant when retrieving information (except if you're using * everytime), so I still can't understand what `forces` you to do so. Please explain, I'm curious of the reason.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support inserting new columns at a specific position in the table, nor can you move columns around. If you ***absolutely must have*** this, then you have no other choice than to create the new table with the correct structure (and order of columns) and copy over the data from the existing table

Comment: Ragu, In my database all table has last column like DateCreated,LastModified. If i create new column in this table at last position that not good.So only i asked to insert in middle position.and also we are not using * in select statement

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this programmatically without creating a new table.

if you are allowed to create and delete tables then:
create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size),
column_name2 data_type(size),
...
);
```

move the data from your main table to the new one then delete the old table.

```
DROP TABLE my_table
```

after all rename the new table to the name of which was on your old deleted table.

--alternative:
you can reorder columns in your host application if possible!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you may try the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_TableName
    (
    Emp_id INT NOT NULL,
    Emp_Name VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Gender BIT NULL,
    [Address] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    phoneNo int NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Tmp_TableName)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_TableName (Emp_id, Emp_Name, [Address],phoneNo)
        SELECT Emp_id, Emp_Name, [Address],phoneNo FROM dbo.TableName WITH     (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TableName
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_TableName', N'TableName', 'OBJECT' 
GO
COMMIT
```

Make sure to change TableName to your actual table name.

Giannis

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but what for?

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca562/1)

```
Alter table T ADD Gender varchar(10);

Alter table T ADD Address2 varchar(100),phoneNo2 varchar(100);
update T set Address2=Address,PhoneNo2=PhoneNo;
Alter table T DROP COLUMN Address,PhoneNo;

Alter table T ADD Address varchar(100),phoneNo varchar(100);
update T set Address=Address2,PhoneNo=PhoneNo2;
Alter table T DROP COLUMN Address2,PhoneNo2;
```